# How to configure JSP app to handle JNDI transparently on Jboss and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, datasource, jndi

I developed an application which is currently running on Jboss with JNDI, but I'd like to run it on Tomcat with minimal reconfiguration by user who will be given .WAR file.

Is this possible, and how?

Jboss 7.1.3
Tomcat 7.0

EDIT:

This is a part of a code I'm using currently with Jboss:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
Connection conn = null;
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
String DATASOURCE_CONTEXT = initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/dbJNDIds").toString();
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
conn = datasource.getConnection();
```

This is the JNDI definition in standalone.xml:

```
<xa-datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDatasource" pool-name="MyDatasource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
        jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=MyDatabase;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;username=sa;password=sa
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <driver>sqljdbc</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>1000</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
    </xa-pool>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

This is the JNDI reference in web.xml (for Jboss):

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>dbJNDIds</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>java:jboss/datasources/MyDatasource</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

So, I'd like to add web.xml JNDI definition "dbJNDIds" (on which I reference in .JSP) that will work on Tomcat along with current Jboss configuration, so I don't have to recompile different version of a project just for Tomcat etc.
Also, it would be nice to see some other possibilities, like for Glassfish...

Comment: It depends on what Java EE elements you use, what version of JBoss you're currently using and what version of Tomcat you wan to migrate. If you don't reduce the scope of your question, it can be closed as too broad.

Comment: Example code added with some additional comments...